# How to avoid double booking in CiviEvent

Tags: civievent

I am on civi 5.11
I have setup an event with a price set. I have set maximum number of participant as 1. Someone already registered online, so price should have shown as sold out, which online works fine.

But from backend one volunteer was able to book another person because the price was still valid option to chose. No warning was shown either. Now there's double booking for 2 people, whereas only 1 person should have been registered.

Is it a glitch? How can I fix it please? thanks

EDIT: when I try to edit the payment, then it shows "Sold Out". But otherwise continues to take participants from backend. I am adding picture to show how it appears during registration and when editing for changing selection.

[image: When adding new participants]

[image: when changing selection]